# Retrieving personal information after the SearchFacesByImage is successful for the face match in amazon rekognition

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to create an app which makes use of **Amazon Rekogition** in AWS for identification of a person and retrieving the personal information for an internal storage system.

I wanted to know how to connect the Amazon Rekognition part and the information stored in the database. The face detection part will be done by Amazon Rekognition, but how will my app store and retrieve the personal information after detection of face?

Can anyone give me a sample code in Java for retrieving the information stored in `dynamodb` using `externalImageId`?

Answer (score 0):

That is totally up to you and how you code your application!

Presumably you will want to store information about the person when the Face is initially stored in Rekognition. Therefore, your application should:

- Store the person's details in Amazon DynamoDB (or a database of your choice)
- Add the face to the Face Collection in Amazon Rekognition, using an `externalImageId` that links the face to the person's entry in the database

When a face is later provided for lookup:

- Search for the face in Amazon Rekognition, which will return the `externalImageId`
- Retrieve the matching data from the database using the `externalImageId`

All of that logic is *your responsibility* to code into an application. You can search the web for code samples of how to use DynamoDB and Rekognition.